# Load multiple increasing json files by ELK stack

Tags: json, elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-stack, logstash-file

I crawled a lot of JSON files in data folder, which all named by timestamp (`./data/2021-04-05-12-00.json`, `./data/2021-04-05-12-30.json`, `./data/2021-04-05-13-00.json`, ...).

Now I'm tring to use ELK stack to load those increasing JSON files.

The JSON file is pretty printed like:

```
{
    "datetime": "2021-04-05 12:00:00", 
    "length": 3,
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 97816,
            "num_list": [1,2,3],
            "meta_data": "{'abc', 'cde'}"
            "short_text": "This is data 97816"
        },
        {
            "id": 97817,
            "num_list": [4,5,6],
            "meta_data": "{'abc'}"
            "short_text": "This is data 97817"
        },
        {
            "id": 97818,
            "num_list": [],
            "meta_data": "{'abc', 'efg'}"
            "short_text": "This is data 97818"
        },
    ],

}
```

I tried using logstash [`multiline`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-codecs-multiline.html) plugins to extract json file, but it seems like it will handle each file as an event. Is there any way to extract each record in JSON `data` fileds as an event ?

Also, what's the best practice for loading multiple increasing pretty-printed JSON files in ELK ?

Answer (score 0):

Using multiline is correct if you want to handle each file as one input event.

Then you need to leverage the [`split` filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-split.html) in order to create one event for each element in the `data` array:

```
filter {
  split {
    field => "data"
  }
}
```

So Logstash reads one file as a whole, it passes its content as a single event to the filter layer and then the `split` filter as shown above will spawn one new event for each element in the `data` array.